# Spring MVC @SessionAttribute: how to remove the attribute from session

Tags: session, spring-mvc, attributes

I use @SessionAttribute("myForm") to store myForm in the session. I can get myForm from the session with no problem. But when I was trying to remove myForm from the session, it looks like I couldn't remove it by using removeAttribute("myForm").

```
    MyForm myForm = (MyForm)request.getSession().removeAttribute("myForm");
    if(myForm != null){
          request.getSession().removeAttribute("myForm"); 
     }
     //get myForm again to check if it has been removed.
     myForm = (MyForm)request.getSession().removeAttribute("myForm");
     //Check it again and the myForm IS NOT NULL after removal.
```

I am not sure what's wrong with it. Any thoghts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you've shown is in the same method?

Comment: Yes, do the check just after removeAttribute() being called.